# Discord getting user roles from exact guild and removing a specific role if conditions match

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently programming a discord bot in python that automatically removes a specific role called 'Onboarding' if a user profile is updated by choosing one or more roles other than this role.

When I run the code I don'tget any bugs but still it doesn't remove the role called 'Onboarding' if a user picks one or more of the other roles.

Can someone please give advice?
This is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import os

my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN']
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive


bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    travel_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | travel") 
    onboarding_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name="Onboarding")
    art_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | art")
    awareness_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | awareness")
    blogging_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | blogging-vlogging")
    books_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | books")
    business_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | business-career")
    comedy_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | comedy-entertainment")
    education_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | education")
    fashion_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | fashion-beauty")
    family_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | family-relationships")
    food_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | food")
    gaming_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | gaming")
    health_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name="️‍♀️ | health-fitness")
    it_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | it-electronics")
    luxury_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | luxury-lifestyle")
    motorsports_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | motorsports")
    movies_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | movies-series")
    music_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | music")
    poetry_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | poetry")
    sustainability_role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=" | sustainability-environment")

    
    if onboarding_role in after.guild.roles and (art_role in after.guild.roles or awareness_role in after.guild.roles or blogging_role in after.guild.roles or books_role in after.guild.roles or business_role in after.guild.roles or comedy_role in after.guild.roles or education_role in after.guild.roles or fashion_role in after.guild.roles or family_role in after.guild.roles or food_role in after.guild.roles or gaming_role in after.guild.roles or health_role in after.guild.roles or it_role in after.guild.roles or luxury_role in after.guild.roles or motorsports_role in after.guild.roles or movies_role in after.guild.roles or music_role in after.guild.roles or poetry_role in after.guild.roles or sustainability_role in after.guild.roles or travel_role in after.guild.roles):
       await after.remove_roles(onboarding_role)

keep_alive()

bot.run(my_secret)
```

- changing after.guild.roles to after.roles --> no result
- otherwise clueless… :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents) problem.

You are setting [default](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.default) intents: `bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())`, which doesn't include the [members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.members) intent (needed so [on_member_update()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.on_member_update) event get enabled).

The change should be as simple as:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also, with your current code (`if onboarding_role in after.guild.roles and ...`) you are checking if the role exists in the guild (`Guild.roles`), not if the member has the role (`Member.roles`). You should change `after.guild.roles` by `after.roles` in the `if` statement (same after the `and`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the answer to my problem. Works like a charm now! ✨ Thanks again + cheere